# Does the second law of thermodynamics cause aging?

Tags: senescence, death, dna-damage

What is the current understanding as to why organisms age and die? In the following explanation on [Ask an Engineer](http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/must-all-organisms-age-and-die), entropy is not even considered (despite it being answered by an engineer). Unless you consider

> accumulation of damage to an organism over time

as a result of entropy ?

In the end, is the eventual death of any organism a result of how the laws of universe? In the paper [Aging of the brain, entropy, and Alzheimer disease](http://www.neurology.org/content/67/8/1340.short), the author states that

> Increasing entropy, manifest through a complex network of interacting ARCs, is seen as the fundamental driving cause of neural and cognitive decline in the elderly

where the abbreviation ARC stands for age-related changes.

Comment: Living organisms are not closed systems, and as far as I am aware, the laws of thermodynamics only apply to closed systems.

Answer (score 6):

**Second law of thermodynamic and ageing**

The second law of thermodynamic applies to closed system. Organisms are not closed system. The second law of thermodynamic is a fundamental principle of our universe and any biological processes do follow the principles of physics. However, stating that biological ageing is (partially) caused by the second law of thermodynamic suggests a big misunderstanding of what the second law of thermodynamic is.

To have a better understanding of the second law of thermodynamic, check up the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) or one of the many other sources of information on the subject and ask questions on [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) if needed.

**Ageing and its evolution**

The evolution of ageing (or senescence) is a big subject and has already been subject of a large number of questions on Biology.SE. Have a look at the [questions tagged](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%3Cageing%3E) . Below are two examples of post that will interest you:

- [Why do we age? or Do we have a theory of senescence?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/344/why-do-we-age-or-do-we-have-a-theory-of-senescence)
- [Why does evolution not make our life longer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/why-does-evolution-not-make-our-life-longer?rq=1)

There is also a [wikipedia page on the evolution of ageing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_ageing).

Note btw that [biological immortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_immortality) and [negligible senescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_senescence) do exist.