# Papers linking telomeres and aging

Tags: genetics, dna, senescence, telomere

I'm currently writing a piece of work about telomeres and aging, and wondered if you could share some good papers you've either read or know of.

Comment: This question is not really a good fit for the Q&A format, the topic is rather broad, there is a nearly endless list of possible responses with no real criteria on what is a better answer. If you have any specific questions you encounter in your research you are certainly welcome to ask them.

Comment: the editors are kind of a pain here.  a good example would be why do we believe that telomeres are related to ageing? or What is the evidence that telomeres are related to aging.

Comment: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/186/is-telomere-length-a-reliable-measure-of-health-lifespan?rq=1  did you look at this one?

Comment: also take a look at this link: http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/begin/traits/telomeres/